# How to get Html code by fetching web API response?

Tags: react-native

When we are trying to fetch html code via fetch API response but we are enable to get it because it return "Unexpected Token <"

```
onLoginService2 = async () => {
    try {
    var hittingURl = "https://members.iracing.com/membersite/Login?username=dave@rms55.com.au&password=rms55Pa55&utcoffset=-600&todaysdate=1558055491688&checkbox=0";
    const myRequest = new Request(hittingURl.toString(),
    {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
    'Accept': 'text/html',
    'Content-Type': 'text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1',
    },
    timeout: 1000,
    // body: JSON.stringify("")
    }
    );

    fetch(myRequest)
    .then((response) => console.log("abcdefghijklmon--> "+JSON.stringify(response)))
    .then((data) => {
    console.log("RESPONSERR----> ",data+"");
    // this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    // this.onLoginSuccessFull(responseJson)

    })
    .catch((error) => {
    this.setState({ isLoading: false })
    console.log("response--31" + error);
    })
    } catch{

    }
    // }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `response` of first `then` has a method `.text()`, which return `Promise`

Try this

```
fetch(myRequest)
    .then(resp => resp.text())
    .then(text => {
        //text is html
    })
```

*Just copy the above and run in console to see the result.

Comment: It returns Possible Unhandled Promise Rejection (id: 0):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 1
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Comment: off course, the text you get from `resp.text()` is purely html string